# Parsing a G4 file to generate doc / schema

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I realize this question is a bit *meta*, but I essentially want to parse an ANTLR4 grammar (an actual .g4 file) to then generate documentation and other artifacts *based on the grammar* (not an instance of the grammar).

For example, consider the [example Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) that contains this rule:

```
compilationUnit
:   packageDeclaration? importDeclaration* typeDeclaration* EOF
;
```

I want to be able to parse the Java.g4 file and produce documentation that says "A compilationUnit contains an optional packageDeclaration, 0 or more importDeclarations, and 0 or more typeDeclarations".  Or perhaps I want to produce an XSD with a data type called "compilationUnit" that contains "packageDeclaration", "importDeclaration", and "typeDeclaration" elements (with proper cardinality set).

What is the best way of accomplishing something like this?  Is it to create a target (even though the goal isn't to create lexers/parsers), or is it to use the [example antlr4 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/ANTLRv4Lexer.g4) to parse the g4 file, or is it something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a very typical use of ANTLR, and convenient given the existing ANTLR 4 grammar.

Comment: I think the typical use of ANTLR is to parse a file that _conforms_ to a grammar -- not to parse the grammar (g4) file itself.  For example, a typical use is to use the Java.g4 to parse a Java file -- but what I want is to parse the Java.g4 directly.

There is an example ANTLR grammar which I might be able to use, but it's not actually a part of the ANTLR4 project -- so I'm not sure how valid it is.  Are you aware of an official g4 file representing the actual ANTLR4 grammar for defining grammars?

Comment: The ANTLR4 grammar in `github.com/antlr/grammars-v4` is fully compliant with ANTLR 4.5. I use it extensively to analyze other Antlr grammars -- it is used as the basis for AntlrDT, the Eclipse ANTLR grammar editor.

Comment: Great.  Thank you so much!  I'll take that same approach then!